# vue @click function only half works?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, click

i'm working here:
http://nufaith.ca/justinatkins/index.html

feel free to view my source, app.js code below

EDIT1: i've hidden the transparent logo at the top so now you can see the 2 different hero images for clarity

GOAL: press arrow keys or chevron icons and the main hero image will change + the blurred copy of that image at the top

PROBLEM: when you @click on the chevrons they don't do the same thing as if you press arrow keys

EDIT2:
here is my entire app.js

```
window.Event = new Vue()
Vue.use(VueLazyload)

Vue.component('contact', {
    template: `
            <div class="contact">
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
    `,
})

Vue.component('hero-bg', {
    template: `
            <div class="hero-bg">
                <div class="hero">
                    <img id="pushed" :src="selectedItem.img" />
                </div>
            </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            gridEnabled: false,
            selected: 0,
            thing: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        selectedItem() {
            return info[this.selected]
        },
        maxImages() {
            return info.length - 1
        }
    },
    created() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (e.keyCode === 37) {
                this.previous()
                return
            }

            if (e.keyCode === 39) {
                this.next()
                return
            }
        })
        Event.$on('updateImg', (index) => {
            this.selected = index
            this.gridEnabled = !this.gridEnabled
        })
    },
    methods: {
        next() {
            this.selected === this.maxImages ? this.selected = 0 : this.selected += 1
        },
        previous() {
            this.selected === 0 ? this.selected = this.maxImages : this.selected -= 1
        }   
    }
})  

Vue.component('hero', {
    template: `
        <div class="hero-container" v-if="!gridEnabled">
            <div class="hero">
                <img :src="selectedItem.img" v-if="thing" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="hero-desc">
                <button class="control left" @click="previous">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-left"></i>
                </button>
                <span class="hero-desc-title" v-html="title"></span>
                <button class="control right" @click="next">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right"></i>
                </button>
                <br/>
                <button class="view-all-button" @click="enableGrid">OVERVIEW</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            gridEnabled: false,
            selected: 0,
            thing: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        selectedItem() {
            return info[this.selected]
        },
        title() {
            const comma = this.selectedItem.title.indexOf((','))
            const len = this.selectedItem.title.length
            const strBeginning = this.selectedItem.title.substring(comma, 0)
            const strEnd = this.selectedItem.title.substring(comma, len)
            if (this.selectedItem.title.includes(',')) {
                return `<span>${strBeginning}<span class="font-regular font-muted">${strEnd}</span></span>`
            }
            return this.selectedItem.title
        },
        maxImages() {
            return info.length - 1
        }
    },
    created() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (e.keyCode === 37) {
                this.previous()
                return
            }

            if (e.keyCode === 39) {
                this.next()
                return
            }
        })
        Event.$on('updateImg', (index) => {
            this.selected = index
            this.gridEnabled = !this.gridEnabled
        })
    },
    methods: {
        next() {
            this.selected === this.maxImages ? this.selected = 0 : this.selected += 1
        },
        previous() {
            this.selected === 0 ? this.selected = this.maxImages : this.selected -= 1
        },
        enableGrid() {
            this.gridEnabled = !this.gridEnabled
            window.scroll(0, 0)
            Event.$emit('enableGrid')
        }
    }
})

Vue.component('grid', {
    template: `
        <div class="grid" v-if="gridEnabled">
            <div class="grid-item aspect" v-for="(item, index) in info" @click="updateImg(index)">
                <img v-lazy="item.img"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    created() {
        Event.$on('enableGrid', () => this.gridEnabled = !this.gridEnabled)
    },
    data() {
        return {
            gridEnabled: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        info() {
            return info
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateImg(index) {
            this.gridEnabled = !this.gridEnabled
            window.scroll(0, 0)
            Event.$emit('updateImg', index)
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

Comment: Would be better if you could include the code snippets here or supply a fiddle example (i.e. https://jsfiddle.net/) for others to follow rather than posting your own url.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the difference in the behaviour of chevrons vs keypress?

Comment: @StarkButtowski the difference on my end is when i press the chevrons, the blurred image at the top does NOT change, but the hero below it does - with keypress everything works fine and the images cycle accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you listening to key press in both components `hero` and `hero-bg`. But Chevron click is handled by only on component `hero`, so only the main image is changing.

This can be solved by ways.

## 1. Having separate component

Have a separate component for chevrons. Emit `Events` on clicking on the buttons and listen in both components `hero` and `hero-bg`.

```
this.$emit('chevron-left', true);
this.$emit('chevron-right', true);
```

On receiving the events, trigger respective `previous()` or `next()` methods to change the images.

## 2. Emit a separate event for chevron

From component `hero` emit an event on chevron click and listen it in `hero-bg` and call the methods accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i've been trying option 2 all day but i can't seem to figure it out, could you please write it for me?

Comment: @JamesBameron I see in your demo that you figured out. is it?

Comment: yes @Stark Buttowski i have figured it out, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It works whether using keys or arrow icons. I think your problem is the image sizes. Open inspect and find `.app .hero-container .hero img` when you press arrows or click icons you can see the changes. But it takes pretty much time.

[image: On the network panel you can see the passed time and image sizes]

Comment: you get the same behaviour when pressing the keyboard as you do clicking on the chevrons? both of the hero images change equally?

Answer (score 0):

Its beacaus of the photos sizes, the proof is that after loading an image for the first time, you wont have the same problem again. I suggest you to preload the photos before rendering (or on rendering) the page. Tack a look on this link:

[Fastest way to preload/load large images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482536/fastest-way-to-preload-load-large-images)

Comment: is this because of the lazyload? i don't understand how keyboard presses work but clicking the chevron doesn't?

Comment: I checked, in both cases (mouse click & keybord click) we have the problem, but, the probability of having this problem by mouse clicks is higher. Its dependend on the devices performance, so that's why there are a specific keybord for gamers, because of the sensibility is higher in such a keybords.