# How to load a high res background image without impacting large contentful paint on page load

Tags: javascript

I'm using lighthouse to measure page performance and I noticed, even if i use a low resolution background image and load the high one with javascript it still affects the larget contentful paint on lighthouse even when i wait until page is fully loaded... Is there something am i missing?

```
window.onload = function () {
        const header = document.querySelector('.header');
        header.style.backgroundImage =
            'url(assets/img/the-image.webp)';
};
```

here is the link to the page. The low res image is hidden behind an overlay while the high res is being loaded

https://nifty-cori-b75591.netlify.app/

[image]

Comment: use some lazyload plugins, like `lazysizes`

Comment: @demkovych not sure lazy load will help, i edited my question to background image and not image

Comment: u can try to preload your image: `<link rel="preload" as="image" href="assets/img/the-image.webp">` or upload it into some CDN

Comment: Isn't the value for `backgroundImage` missing a closing parenthesis in your snippet?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky yes but fixed, had to edit before posting so i mistyped it. Thanks

Comment: Lighthouse usually suggests the improvements you can make. Can you share either a link to the page or share the generated lighthouse report. The link would be more helpful though.

Comment: I think you should use a CDN

Comment: @JackSparrow i provided a link you can check

Comment: @Jackal According to https://web.dev/lcp/#what-is-a-good-lcp-score you are meeting a good LCP score. I'm beginning to wonder if this is a problem worth solving and is your attempt a case of over optimizing. Maybe others can chime in here. 

You could try a few other things like caching the image and using CDN or reducing the area of the header itself though I don't think it will improve your LCP.

Anyways, just go through the link and see if there is a need and possibility to reduce the LCP time. You may have to do away with the full height header image.

Comment: @JackSparrow just trying to understand how content impacts performance. I tried a setTimeout on the function in page load, 5 seconds and that was enough to avoid the large contentful paint. However it does not seem a good way to solve this. It seems the best is to use an image and use lazy loading

Comment: As per https://blog.chromium.org/2020/05/introducing-web-vitals-essential-metrics.html - Largest Contentful Paint measures perceived load speed and marks the point in the page load timeline when the page's main content has likely loaded. I think you have pretty much done everything and it was a good choice to go with @AurelienB answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have become keen on not using "background-image" for my high res background image.

I prefer to have something like :

```
<style>
    .BackgroundImage-Container {
        position: relative;
        width : 100%;
        height : 100%;
    }

    .BackgroundImage {
        position: absolute;
        top : 0;
        right : 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width : 100%;
        height : 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
</style>

<picture class="BackgroundImage-Container">
    <img class="BackgroundImage" src="./some-image.png" />
</picture>
```

So I am able to use any `lazyload`, `srcset`, `<source media="" ></source>` that pleases me.

Comment: Tried this approach and seems to work nicely if using `loading="lazy"`. Unfortunely that doesn't have support for iOS

Comment: I decided to use your answer, and change my code to use an image instead a background div. There are too many advantages of using an image, specially the srcset and SEO. Lazy Loading, while i can use the simple native one, I'll use intersection observer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do Lazy Loading with Blurred Image Effect, couple of useful links for you!

[see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482536/fastest-way-to-preload-load-large-images):

> #:~:text=attr('large%2Dclass',having%20to%20change%20the%20js!

https://tsucres.me/2017-12-01/Progressive-image-load.html

https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/